# clang++ 8.0.1 self-assign-overloaded warnings

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings, clang++

Consider this code:

```cpp
class Vector {
public:
    Vector& operator+=(const Vector &v) { return *this; }
    Vector& operator-=(const Vector &v) { return *this; }
    Vector& operator*=(const Vector &v) { return *this; }
    Vector& operator/=(const Vector &v) { return *this; }
};

int main()
{
    Vector v;
    v += v;
    v -= v;
    v *= v;
    v /= v;
}
```

When compiled with clang++ 8.0.1, I get the following warnings:

```
$ clang++ -Wall example2.cpp -o example2
example2.cpp:13:7: warning: explicitly assigning value of variable of type 'Vector' to
      itself [-Wself-assign-overloaded]
    v -= v;
    ~ ^  ~
example2.cpp:15:7: warning: explicitly assigning value of variable of type 'Vector' to
      itself [-Wself-assign-overloaded]
    v /= v;
    ~ ^  ~
2 warnings generated.
```

What problem does the warning try to point out? Why is there no such warning for `operator+=` and `operator*=`?

**Edit:** For a motivation (or real-world usage of such self-assign expressions) see https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/1893

**Edit 2:** I simplified the code by removing everything but the return statements from the operators; the same problem still occurs.

Comment: I reported a bug for clang: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=43124

Answer (score 3):

Here's my guess:

Clang recognizes that *for scalars* `v -= v` means `v = 0`.

It assumes that every time you use `v -= v`, it's a fancy way of saying `v = 0`.

But since `v` is a class with overloaded `-=`, it warns you that in this case `v -= v` might not be equivalent to `v = 0`.

It's does the same thing for `v /= v`, because it's equivalent to `v = 1` for scalars (unless `v == 0`).

---

If I got the reasoning corrent, this is a pretty stupid warning, IMO.

I'd rather warn on `v -= v;` and `v /= v;` being used on scalars.

Comment: Well, it might make sense assuming that all possible overloaded operators do arithmetic operations. I even removed the underlying arithmetics from my example in the last edit, so the compiler cannot even contemplate about it...

Comment: @JakubKlinkovský any number minus it self is 0 and every number divided by it self is 1.

Comment: @Tony Obviously, but my class is not a number. C++ allows to do anything in the overloaded arithmetic operators, even non-arithmetic operations (and my example does not do any). See the link at the end of my question for a real-world non-trivial and non-arithmetic example of self-assignment expressions using overloaded operators.